# Confusion with propellant pressure in gun barrel

Tags: pressure, projectile

I'm trying to use 2 equations from a report I found called "Simplified Equations of Interior Ballistics" by Joseph E. Mayer:

> p_max = (p_q/e)[1+3/4(γ-1)]^-1

> p_q = (2qCλ/aw)^2[W/g(v_c-17.7C)]

What I'm trying to do with this is find the muzzle velocity of a projectile leaving the barrel. The first time I tried doing this, I made an absent minded mistake and forgot to square (2qCλ/aw), but I got an expected answer of ~500 m/s anyway. Yet when I tried correcting myself, I got an absurd ~4,500 m/s. I am using 5 lb of RDX as the propellant. Is squaring necessary, and if so/not so, why or why not?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Why do you consider the second result "absurd."  RDX has a sufficient expansion velocity that a very light projectile with very little barrel friction could lead to absurd muzzle velocities.